# Chrome App: Execute function defined in an app window from a background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a basic canvas game as a chrome app. When I minimize the game window, the game continues playing by itself. I would like to execute a function, `pause()`, when the window is minimized.

index.js (included via `<script>` tag in index.html)

```
...

function pause(){
  paused = true;
  pausebtn.classList.add('hidden');
  pausemenu.classList.remove('hidden');
}

...
```

background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    'outerBounds': {
      'width': screen.availWidth,
      'height': screen.availHeight
    }
  });
});
```

Where do I put `chrome.app.window.onMinimized.addListener()`?

Then, from there, how do I actually execute the function `pause()`?

I'm looking for something along these lines:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    'outerBounds': {
      'width': screen.availWidth,
      'height': screen.availHeight
    }
  });
});
chrome.app.window.onMinimized.addListener(function(gamewindow){
  gamewindow.pause();
});
```

Comment: You are dangerously misusing terminology: this is _not_ a content script.

Comment: @Xan Oh yeah... Thanks for changing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it seems like [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window) does not really show properly how to attach those events: they are attached to window instances, e.g.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    'outerBounds': {
      'width': screen.availWidth,
      'height': screen.availHeight
    }
  }, function(createdWindow) {
    createdWindow.onMinimized.addListener(function() {
      /* code goes here */
    });
  });
});
```

There are at least three possible answers, a direct one and a one-more-abstraction-layer one, and move-your-logic one.

### Direct:

Call the method directly, by using `contentWindow` attribute:

```
createdWindow.contentWindow.pause();
```

This tightly couples the code though: if you ever refactor your app's code, you'll need to refactor the background script too.

### Abstraction:

Pass a message, then process it in the game.

```
// background
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({pause: true});

// app window
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(message.pause) {
    pause();
  }
});
```

### Move logic:

Your app's scripts are *not* content scripts. They are not restricted in API access, and as such can listen to the event themselves - and it's probably the least awkward method.

```
// app window
chrome.app.window.current().onMinimized.addListener(pause);
```

..yep, that's it. Much cleaner than trying to pass the command around.

Comment: Thanks so much. Best answer I've ever received. Beyond helpful.